# Django OAuth Toolkit Toen Generation

Tags: django, oauth, token, toolkit

Using Django OAuth Toolkit, I have authorization_grant_type set to password and skip_authorization set to true. I am able to generate tokens and refresh tokens using curl without an issue using the following command:

```
curl -X POST -d "grant_type=password&username=username&password=password" http://p6ge67ihXcwECuy7Z7iomyv16VlEk4uX6B886UWl:NZK5WUWsdb1oI1aAXAy3EOLx6zbXBrtVEIUoI7pK9ZLpwkMTvIcq3FMycHklGjJazHj4TguPPvpEL1JNmL6uZz594DjNk99nKu6Uq4Z66mM26AWD63D9WO449exUjYq3@localhost:8000/o/token/
```

But when I try substituting this command with a POST and invoke that POST from a Django view, I get the following:

```
<Response [401]>
Unauthorized: /o/token/
```

Any clue why this happening? My POST code is as follows:

```
data = {
'grant_type': 'password',
'username': 'username',
'password': 'password'
}

response =
```

requests.post('http://p6ge67ihXcwECuy7Z7iomyv16VlEk4uX6B886UWl:NZK5WUWsdb1oI1aAXAy3EOLx6zbXBrtVEIUoI7pK9ZLpwkMTvIcq3FMycHklGjJazHj4TguPPvpEL1JNmL6uZz594DjNk99nKu6Uq4Z66mM26AWD63D9WO449exUjYq3@localhost:8000/o/token/', data=data)

What am I missing? Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: what is the value of `response.contents`?

Comment: Okay, now I added a header (headers = {'Content-Type': 'application/json'}) to the POST call and response.contents = b'{"error": "unsupported_grant_type"}'. Apparently the client ID and client secret are now being accepted but the grant type isn't. And even if I change the grant type to authorization_code, the error persists. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Check in Django admin (/admin/oauth2_provider/application, in my case) if the grant type is accepted for that `Application`:

[image]

try `Resource owner password-based` or `Client credentials`

Comment: It's set to "Resource owner password-based". When I make the call using cURL from the command line it generates and retrieves the token but not when I try to call the same service using a POST call. Any more thoughts?

Comment: Any other suggestions? Thanks.